# Xamarin Forms iOS realm DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: xcode, xamarin.forms, realm

I'm having problems deploying my app. I'm getting this after failed deployment:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(975,3): warning : [xma]: An error occurred on the receiver while executing a post for topic xvs/build/execute-task/AppName.iOS/be46a7d002fCodesign and client buildbe46a7dea89e48e793bc0f9a0cc351c537bea3be9755ca474d2a7810526c87cc25572Me
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(975,3): warning : An error occurred on client Build169000292 while executing a reply for topic xvs/build/execute-task/AppName.iOS/be46a7d002fCodesign
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(975,3): warning :    at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.ApplicationMessageExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<OfResponse>b__1(MqttApplicationMessage m) in C:\A\1\230\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\Extensions\ApplicationMessageExtensions.cs:line 194
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(975,3): warning :    at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Select`2.Selector._.OnNext(TSource value) in d:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Linq\Observable\Select.cs:line 39
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(975,3): warning : --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(975,3): warning :    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(975,3): warning :    at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.<PostAsync>d__21`2.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\230\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingClient.cs:line 190
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(975,3): error : MessagingRemoteException: An error occurred on client Build169000292 while executing a reply for topic xvs/build/execute-task/AppName.iOS/be46a7d002fCodesign
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(975,3): error : AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(975,3): error : DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/Users/username/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/AppName.iOS/be46a7dea89e48e793bc0f9a0cc351c537bea3be9755ca474d2a7810526c87cc/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone11.8-14.4.1/AppName.iOS.app/Frameworks/realm-wrappers.framework/_CodeSignature'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(975,3): error :
```

It seems to be related to realm, but just a week ago it worked fine.
I've tried various supposed solutions i've found when googling - cleaning buildfolders, deleting bin and obj folders, cleaning the cache on buildhost found at path ~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs.

I have a valid developer certificate, and provisioning profile - so that should not be the issue..

Finaly i verified i could actually connect to the buildhost by creating a new blank project, and it worked just fine - UNTIL i added realm.

I'm all up to date with latest version of xcode and visual studio. I've spend a lot of time trying to fix this, so i'm hoping someone can help with a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you are using the latest Visual Studio 2019 16.9.5 But i had similar issue (except around SkiaSharp) when I upgraded to this version which also triggered an Update of iOS SDK on my mac.

I reinstalled Visual Studio 16.9.3 as second install, which then rolled back the iOS SDK on Mac and now can build same project fine again.

Unsure if its VS or the iOS SDK or both?

You can download old release here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history#installing-an-earlier-release

and then need to run installer in command line if you want to ride side by side:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio-versions-side-by-side?view=vs-2019

Comment: HI Aaron. Thanks for taking the time to reply. The issue was there before i updated VS, so i don´t think this is the cause.

Comment: Hi Aaron. I too am having this issue since updating to Visual Studio 16.9.5 on Windows and Xcode 12.5 on the MAC build machine. My Xamarin.Forms iOS project will not build. I have sent in feedback to the Visual Studio Developer Forum so maybe Microsoft will help us determine what is happening at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Xamarin-Forms-iOS-SkiaSharp-DirectoryNot/1424416?port=1025&fsid=1586cd95-8b91-43d1-89fb-6a6d2af6bb4a&entry=myfeedback&ref=native&refTime=1621093474002&refUserId=01f94588-7640-4933-8aba-8e45f5739bd1

Comment: Sorry it didn't help you OneBigQuestion.  I wasn't sure where the issue lay as I had updated XCode, Big Sur, Xamarin Forms to v5 and then Visual Studio and Xamarin iOS SDK. (hadnt been on any of them in awhile)

I spent so long looking for answers, and undoing each step, and couldn't find online any info other than similarity to what you had in your question

Thank you for logging with VS Developer forum OrgBrat.

Comment: It is not an actual fix, but i was able to deploy my app from VS Mac instead of from VS PC

Comment: Can confirm that downgrading to 16.9.3 fixed the issue for me -- thanks! Still works fine with Xcode 12.5. I tried 16.10.0 and ran into a different issue (actool sharing violation), FYI.

Comment: @IGx89 fixed the same issue as Aron or the issue i posted?

Comment: A DirectoryNotFoundException for a _CodeSignature directory, which I’m assuming is the same issue as both you and Aron. There’s a chance 16.10.0 fixes that issue, but I ran into a different issue on that version (sharing violation on asset files) so I can’t verify that myself. Going to stick with 16.9.3 for a while — can’t afford losing another half day to Xamarin bugs :/